# Target radio button by value css

Tags: css, input

I have some HTML like:

```
<input type="radio" value="red" id="color" name="attribute_color">
<input type="radio" value="blue" id="color" name="attribute_color">
<input type="radio" value="green" id="color" name="attribute_color">
```

How can I target the different inputs WITHOUT adding any ID or class? Can I target by value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes you can define your css rules like so:

```
input[value="red"] {
   /* style for red radio */
}

input[value="green"] {
   /* style for green radio */
}

input[value="blue"] {
   /* style for blue radio */
}
```

The attribute selector works on all browser and IE7+

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that a class would work just as well so it seems unnecessary. Unless the `value` has some other use of course.